USB to tiny bulb
I have a couple of small bulbs out of tea lights that I wanted to wire up to a usb cable. They work fine for some time but after a few days they die. I suspect the output is too high for these little bulbs. Is there a way to lower the output so that these bulbs can work without burning out? They originally were battery powered 4.5V, one circuit has two bulbs and the other just one. My charger says it is 2.4A.
Being an absolute newbie I am not sure exactly what that means and I don’t want to create an electric fire so any advice would be great.

Did you remove the bulbs directly from the tea light circuitry or are there other components attached to them?

Yes they are bulbs removed from a mini lantern. They are powered by two AG3 batteries

You could add a diode or two or three in series with the roughly 5V USB output. For example 1N4001 (or 1N400x where x is 1 to 7).
The lamps will last longer the dimmer they are, but they will also change to a redder colour and emit less (visible) light.
That's assuming they are incandescent bulbs. If they are LEDs then we need to see the circuit.
